# mySQL ERROR #1349 View's SELECT contain a sub query in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

CREATE VIEW tbloffer_merchant 
AS (
SELECT `MerchantID`,`ProductCode`,`OfferID`,`Visibility`,`Status`,`ReplyMessage`,`ReferenceNumber`,`Price`,`Date`,`RequestID`,`CompanyName`,`OverallRating` FROM(
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM `tbloffer`)AS a NATURAL JOIN `tbloffer_product` GROUP BY `OfferID`) AS a 
NATURAL JOIN (
SELECT `ProductCode`,`MerchantID` FROM `tblproduct`)AS b)As c 
NATURAL JOIN (
SELECT `MerchantID`,`CompanyName`,`OverallRating` FROM `tblmerchant`) AS d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, too bad MySQL does not allow this.
The simple solution is usually to create more views for all your other SELECT statements in the view to prevent all the code between ( )

So a view for:

```
SELECT ProductCode,MerchantID FROM tblproduct
```

And one for

```
SELECT MerchantID,CompanyName,OverallRating FROM tblmerchant
```

And replace:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM tbloffer)
```

with:

```
SELECT * FROM tbloffer
```

Comment: Thank you so much.....
but unfortunately I did not have enough reputation for vote your answer